# Dojo dialog - how to save contents of dialog

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am new to dojo and I have been following the tutorials mentioned here
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/Dialog.html

I am not sure how to capture the data entered in dialog

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 require(["dojo/ready", "dijit/Dialog", "dijit/form/Button"], 

  function(ready, Dialog, Button){
    ready(function(){
        var myDialog = new Dialog({
            title: "Add",
            style: "width: 600px"
        });

        var myButton = new Button({
            onClick: function(){
                myDialog.set("content", getDialog());
                myDialog.show();
            }
        }, "progbutton");
    });
});

function getDialog(){
  return document.getElementById('add-link-dialog-container').innerHTML;
}


</script>
```

Html:

```
  <div id="add-link-dialog-container" style="display:none;"> 
        <div>
           <table class="dijitDialogPaneContentArea">
             <tr>
              <td><label for="name">Name:</label></td>
              <td><input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" name="name" id="name" value="Test"/></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td><label for="address">Address:</label></td>
               <td><input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" name="address" id="address"/></td>
             </tr>
            </table>

           <div class="dijitDialogPaneActionBar">
               <button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="submit" id="ok">Add</button>
               <button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="button" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
           </div>
         </div> 
       </div>
       <button id="progbutton" type="button">Add New</button>
```

The dialog does pop up. But how do I capture the data entered in the fields?
Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the dialog is being opened, then you should be able to use the [`dijit/registry`](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dijit/registry.html) module to retrieve your form fields (and thus, also your values/data).

For example:

```
require([ "dijit/registry" ], function(registry) {
    registry.byId("ok").on("click", function() {
        registry.byId("address").get("value"); // Will return the "address" value
    });
});
```

The question of course is, when do you add the [`onClick`](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dijit/form/Button#1_9dijit_form_Button_onClick) event handler to your button. You have to wait until the dialog is loaded until you can add an event handler to it. Good thing, the `dijit/Dialog` has an event called [`onLoad`](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dijit/Dialog#1_9dijit_Dialog_onLoad) which we can use.

For example:

```
myDialog.on("load", function() {
    registry.byId("ok").on("click", function() {
        registry.byId("address").get("value"); // Will return the "address" value
    });
});
```

However, if you're interesting in submitting all form data, you should take a look at the `dijit/form/Form` widget which allows you to get/set the form values, validate the form and submit it as well.